# Web service with Apache axis

Tags: java, web-services, apache, apache-axis

I created my web service using Eclipse and Apache axis ([Using this link](http://www.softwareagility.gr/index.php?q=node/21)). When I tested it on my local machine with Eclipse and Apchache tomcat it worked fine.
Then I deployed my web service on another machine,using files generated by eclipse. I copied the folder created under `WebContent\WEB-INF\services\AutocompleteService` to Jboss's `server\default\deploy\i2b2.war\WEB-INF\services\AutocompleteService`
When I tried to access my service it gives me following exception.

```
SEVERE: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Required element null defined in the schema can not be found in the request".
```

Here is my small web service (excluding biz logic)

```
public class AutocompleteService
{
  public OMElement getCodes(OMElement input)
  {
    String query = input.getText();
    OMFactory fac = OMAbstractFactory.getOMFactory();
    OMNamespace omNs = fac.createOMNamespace("", "");
    OMElement codes = fac.createOMElement("codes", omNs);
    // some biz logic 

    while (SOME_CONDITION)
    {
          OMElement code = fac.createOMElement("code", null, codes);
          OMAttribute value = fac.createOMAttribute("value", null, tempStr);
          code.addAttribute(value);
     }

      return codes;
    }

}
```

Here is my services.xml file

```
service name="AutocompleteService" >
    <Description>
        Please Type your service description here
    </Description>
    <messageReceivers>
        <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-only" class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver" />
        <messageReceiver  mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-out"  class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver"/>
    </messageReceivers>
    <parameter name="ServiceClass" locked="false">com.service.AutocompleteService</parameter>
</service>
```

Am I missing something ?

**EDIT:** I am using
1) Jboss 4.2.2
2) Axisa 2-1.5.2
3) Tomcat 6

Comment: Could you please add information on the versions being used here for Tomcat, JBoss and Axis2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed my services.xml file and it worked. I am really suprised as the file mentioned in question is generated by Eclipse but it still didn't worked.
I updated my file to

```
<service name="AutocompleteService" >
    <Description>
        Please Type your service description here
    </Description>
    <operation name="getCodes">
        <messageReceiver class="org.apache.axis2.receivers.RawXMLINOutMessageReceiver"/>
    </operation>
    <parameter name="ServiceClass" locked="false">com.service.AutocompleteService</parameter>
</service>
```